# SqlBulkCopy fails with KeepIdentity set to true

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am using SqlBulkCopy to move all the data from one server to another and I need to keep the identity value from the source. Both source and destination table are the same schema when I set KeepIdentity it fails. I read that SqlBulkCopy should set identity_insert on and then off and I also tried to do it in code but keeps failing. When I remove the KeepIdentity it increments the id so I know the code is correct.

> Exception Cannot find the object \"dbo.GuidelineLog\" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

```
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
                {


                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Log";
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
                    bulk
                    // How many Rows you want to insert at a time
                    //bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100000;
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 500;
                    // Set the timeout.
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;

                    bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied +=
                        new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
                    bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 4500;


                    //(                  2093,000 row(s) affected)
                    //Always stopping at 2093,000
                    try
                    {
                        // INSERT only if row doesn't exist in the destination
                        //bulkCopy.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                        // Write from the source to the destination.
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
{0}", ex.Message));
                        return false;
                    }
```

Comment: Can you check your permissions on the destination database? Can we see the connection string?

Comment: @Orwel When I remove KeepIdentity bulkCopy inserts the data into the correct table using the correct connection string, its just when I have it set to true I get this error

Comment: '...you do not have permissions', maybe KeepIdentity needs more permission to work. Can you test with sa login?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have enough permissions. Try directly through SSMS. If that fails, it should convince you that you don't have enough permissions.

Comment: I have the same problem using an account for etl with restricted permissions. The user has SELECT and INSERT permissions on the destination database. If KeepIdentity option is set, then I receive a permission error. If it's set to false, no.I need that option set to true. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It was an permissions problems that had to be adjusted, when I used the SA account it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

A user needs to have `ALTER` permission when using `KeepIdentity = true`.